# RabbitMQ Consumer connection to rabbitMQ in https domain

Tags: java, https, rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

I need to receive messages of a queue, but this queue is inside in another machine(AWS instance) with https(https://www.mymachine.com/rabbitmq) but when I want to establish a connection to the queue I get a NullPointerException.

This is a part of code:

```
factory.setHost(https://www.mymachine.com/rabbitmq);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout");
        queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ, by default, does not use HTTP protocol, it uses AMQP protocol.

you have to change the `factory.setHost` with the ip or hostname.

```
factory.setHost(yourmachine)
```

if you need an SSL connection please read:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html it is very clear tutorial.